# Angular observable / subscribe not working

Tags: observable, angular7

I'm trying to get a value from an observable with angular 7. I have some functions inside a service that look like this

```js
getSomething(): Observable<MyObject[]> {
  let result = new Subject<MyObject[]>();
  this.callApi('hello-world').subscribe(data => {
      console.log('hello-world data: ', data);
      result.next(this._mapToMyObjectArray(data));
  });
  return result.asObservable();
}

_mapToMyObjectArray(data: any): MyObject[] {
    ...
}
```

I'm able to log the hello-world data with no problem (the api is called and responds as I expect).

However, when I try to subscribe to this from another component, such as

```js
doStuff(): void {
    console.log('do stuff with something');
    this.myService.getSomething().subscribe(
        (result) => console.log('result', result),
        (error) => console.log('error', error),
        () => console.log('done')
     );
}
```

When I invoke `doStuff()` I see the first log (`do stuff with something`) but not the other logs (success / error / done).

Can anyone provide some insight? Thanks for your help, I'm sure it's something trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this can help someone. I had a fundamental misunderstanding of the difference between subjects and observers. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47537934/what-is-the-difference-between-a-observable-and-a-subject-in-rxjs).

I solved it by creating an observer instead of a subject within the `getSomething` function.

```
getSomething(): Observable<MyObject[]> {
  var result: Observable<MyObject[]>;
  this.callApi('hello-world').subscribe(data => {
      console.log('hello-world data: ', data);
      result = of(this._mapToMyObjectArray(data));
  });
  return result;
}
```

where `of` is imported from rxjs.