# Confusion around understanding the difference between Observable and Subject in RX

Tags: rxjs, rx-swift, reactivex, frp

After reading a large number of posts on stack overflow, I am still very confused about the difference between Observable and Subject in Rx.

Basically, most people point out that the key difference between the two is that "**The Subject class inherits both Observable and Observer, in the sense that it is both an observer and an observable**", and it can be demonstrated by the following code snippet:

```
var subject = new Rx.Subject();

var subscription = subject.subscribe(
function (x) { console.log('onNext: ' + x); },
function (e) { console.log('onError: ' + e.message); },
function () { console.log('onCompleted'); }
);

subject.onNext(1);
// => onNext: 1

subject.onNext(2);
// => onNext: 2

subject.onCompleted();
// => onCompleted
```

I understand that in the following part of the code, subject is being the role of an observable that can be subscribed to:

```
var subscription = subject.subscribe(
function (x) { console.log('onNext: ' + x); },
function (e) { console.log('onError: ' + e.message); },
function () { console.log('onCompleted'); }
);
```

What really confuses me is this part:

```
subject.onNext(1);
// => onNext: 1

subject.onNext(2);
// => onNext: 2

subject.onCompleted();
// => onCompleted
```

It looks like here it demonstrates that subject can be the role of an observer as well, but my understanding is that here subject is also feeding values/events (sending 1, 2 and complete event). **So why is the subject considered the role of an observer in the code above**?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: subject can be consumed (obserevable) by others  and also as an emitter (observer). When it is used to emit event its role is observer

Comment: In the code you provided the subject acts as an `Observable` only.  
It can be used as [`Observer`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/MiscJSDoc.js~ObserverDoc.html) if you pass it to a `subscribe` function. For example: `interval(1000).subscribe(subject)`

Comment: @FanCheung I though it is the observable that emits events? How come an observer can emit event as well? Could you please elaborate? :)

Comment: maybe you can take a look here first : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47537934/what-is-the-difference-between-a-observable-and-a-subject-in-rxjs

Comment: @FanCheung the link is very helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subject is considered as taking the role of an observer in the referenced code precisely because `onNext` and `onCompleted` are being called on it. An `Observer` is defined as an object on which you can call `onNext` and `onCompleted` (as well as `onError`.)