# observable not updating in template directive

Tags: angular, angularjs, ngrx

I have an `Observable` defined in my component file. It is updating appropriately when interpolated with double curlys (`{{example}}`). But it is not updating inside the template directive, even though I am using an `async` pipe.

`component.html`

```
<ng-container *ngIf="isLoading$ | async as isLoading; else elseBlock">
  is loading
</ng-container>
<ng-template #elseBlock> Add</ng-template>  <--- constantly showing elseblock; not working!
is loading: {{ isLoading$ | async }}        <--- is working correctly
```

`component.ts`

```
  updateIsLoading: any;

  isLoading$ = new Observable((observer) => {
    observer.next(false);

    this.updateIsLoading = function (newValue: boolean) {
      observer.next(newValue);
      observer.complete();
    };
  });

  handleClick() {
    this.updateIsLoading(true);   <--- running this line updates interpolated value, but not the if statement
  }
```

---

### Edit

Apparently, commenting out the second `async` makes the first behave appropriately.

---

Comment: I'm suspicious of the line `observer.complete()`, which I would think would terminate the subscription. Try commenting it out?

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek No dice. Same result.

Comment: Funny, if you comment out `is loading: {{ isLoading$ | async }}` it will work. [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-lamport-vsrycf?file=/src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: @SergeySosunov Oh! Interesting discovery! I will update my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a misunderstanding of the `async` pipe and/or Observables.

Each instance of `isLoading$ | async` creates a *separate* subscription.

This subscription will execute the callback function, overwriting `this.updateIsLoading` with a new function.

So your click handler will only ever fire `observer.next(newValue)` for the last `isLoading$ | async` subscription.

---

Ideally you just want to call `isLoading$ | async` once and put it into a template variable.

Unfortunately Angular doesn't have a built in directive to just declare a single template variable. Although you can write your own, and there are some packages out there like `ng-let`.

You can wrap everything in `*ngIf` with `as` to get a template variable, but that doesn't work if you want to allow falsey values through.

You can use the `ng-template` `let-*` syntax to accomplish it. The idea is to define a template, and pass in your async variables as parameters via `ngTemplateOutletContext`. The actual rendering is done by an `ng-container`.

```html
<ng-container
  [ngTemplateOutlet]="myAsyncTemplate"
  [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{isLoading: isLoading$ | async}"
></ng-container>

<ng-template #myAsyncTemplate let-isLoading="isLoading">
  <ng-container *ngIf="isLoading; else elseBlock">
    <p>is loading: {{isLoading}}</p>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-template #elseBlock> Else Block</ng-template>
  <p>is loading: {{isLoading}}</p>
  <button (click)="handleClick()">SET TO TRUE</button>
</ng-template>
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x4msbz?file=src/main.html

---

Alternatively you can turn the observable into a shared stream like Sergey suggested. That'll let you make any number of subscriptions which all share the same value. Depends on your use case.

Answer (score 2):

Answer is a bit simple and shady at the same time. Here is a small hint:

```
updateIsLoading: any;

isLoading$ = new Observable((observer) => {
  console.log("Created!");
  observer.next(false);

  this.updateIsLoading = function (newValue: boolean) {
    observer.next(newValue);
    observer.complete();
  };
});
```

`Created` will be logged twice in the console. So each time you call `| async` on this Observable - the function you passed to the constructor is executed, and `updateIsLoading` is overwritten, so only last `|async` binding is working.

So if you want to have 2 `async` pipes - use `Subject`.

```
isLoading$ = new Subject<boolean>();

updateIsLoading = (value: boolean) => this.isLoading$.next(value);
```

Note: there is no initial value in Subject, so in the `is loading: (value)` the value will be empty string.

OR you can use `share()` operator:

```
isLoading$ = new Observable((observer) => {
  this.updateIsLoading = function (newValue: boolean) {
    observer.next(newValue);
    observer.complete();
  };
}).pipe(share(), startWith(false));
```

Will work as "expected".

Additional details: [What is the difference between Observable and a Subject in rxjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47537934/what-is-the-difference-between-observable-and-a-subject-in-rxjs)

Answer (score 0):

This will probably be an unpopular answer, but I prefer to keep the templates really simple, and put any necessary complexity in the component, where the full expressiveness of ts/js is available.

In this case, I think that it would be easier / more understandable / maintainable to subscribe in the component, and update a property that can easily be used multiple times in the template without affecting the subscription.

IMHO, the async pipe is just unnecessarily complicating things here.

TLDR: Keep templates simple, and keep their logic simple.

Comment: That works, but you have to remember to manually unsubscribe for certain observables. The ng-let package has the simplest solution, it lets you declare a template variable directly in the `ng-container` tag. So you can wrap your whole template in an ng-container and put your async pipes there. Then you've got a shared template variable with auto unsubscribing. It's probably fairly easy to write your own version of this too. Honestly not sure why this isn't a native feature rather than the clunky outlet context.

Comment: or, you can use the takeUntil(destroyed) pattern, and then you don't have to add a library.

Again, I think that folks are trying to cram too much logic into the 'view' (the template). That's what the component is for.